# BLE - connection Point to Point

Tags: telecommunication, embedded-systems, iot

I'm developing a IoT system, I'm thinking in implementing BLE technology, but I have an unresolved question

**Description of the system**

The system implemented will have a "line" topology, ie. a line of IoT devices all separated by 30 - 50 meters in open field, we need the devices to communicate **just** with the devices at their side, ie. there is no need to move data from the n-device to any other device other than the (n-1)-device or (n+1)-device, by the nature of the topology there can't be any routers, repeaters or devices like that, neither there will be a smartphone, this RF technology is for a secondary RF communication that will be almost always off, it will turn on once a day, maybe even less frequently, and it will stay on for less than an hour.

**The question**

Is BLE suited for this purpose? Can BLE connect device point-to-point, only whit the devices at their side one at a time?, for example, if I have 3 BLE modules (**no smarthphone**) can I connect whit each other? Any BLE protocol that I should be aiming?

**Extra question**

In the same sense I'm thinking in zigbee, all the same questions said before, but whit zigbee, it is possible?

**little disclaimer**

This is very similar to an old question, but in this question I want to focus on whether is possible  to make this connection whit BLE, because for what I have been reading I'm getting the idea that we need the connection whit the devices at the sides will be not possible

Comment: Point of communication is for at least two devices to talk.  As long as you do not need to exclude the other devices, you can do this over any communication method.  It's the exclusion part that you should be aware of; have you overheard something before and thought it was meant for you?